# Getting the difference between two (string) dates in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm receiving from the client app some dates in the form of `2017-03-20 17:01:24` that I wish to compare and extract the number of hours, days, minutes or whatever counter available (I would prefer it flexible).

I saw the `timex` package featuring something like this:

`Duration.diff(Duration.now, Duration.zero, :days)`

My problem is that I don't know how to make this `diff` work with my two dates.

I tried with:

```
end_timex = Timex.parse!("2017-03-20 17:01:24", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", :strftime)
start_timex = Timex.parse!("2017-03-19 17:01:24", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", :strftime)
diff = Duration.diff(end_timex, start_timex, :days)
```

But that obviously fails with:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Timex.Duration.diff/3
    (timex) lib/time/duration.ex:612: Timex.Duration.diff(~N[2017-03-20 17:01:24], ~N[2017-03-19 17:01:24], :days)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you achieve this by doing.

```
end_timex = Timex.parse!("2017-03-20 17:01:24", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", :strftime)
start_timex = Timex.parse!("2017-03-19 17:01:24", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", :strftime)
diff_in_days = Timex.diff(end_timex, start_timex, :days)
---> 1 
diff_in_hours = Timex.diff(end_timex, start_timex, :hours)
---> 24
```

Documented here https://hexdocs.pm/timex/2.1.5/Timex.Comparable.html#diff/3 
Maybe i'm misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Oh God...I always get the habit of over-complicating things when learning a new language. It works, ty.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late but if you need just days you can use `Date.diff`

Code may look like this:

```
  with {:ok, date} <- Date.from_iso8601(string_date) do 
       Date.diff(date, Date.utc_today)
  end
```

Also can be done with `DateTime.diff` if you have `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`